# Javascript Dynamic Form Duplication Issue

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm writing a dynamic form to use as an order form for ordering t-shirts and hoodies, tanks, etc.

**How The Form Is Supposed To Work**

1-You first choose the "Type of Garment" you'd like: T-shirts, hoodies, tanks, or long-sleeves. That then generates the "Garment Style" list.

2-Then choose the "Garment Style" you'd like: Gildan 5000, Tultex 0202TC, etc. This then generates a list of the available colors for that particular garment.

3-Then you choose your color and you are finished.

**The Problem**

When you choose your "Garment Type" it shows the DIV which holds the form information that gives you your color options, as it is supposed to. But, when you choose another "Garment Type", instead of hiding the previous DIV and replacing it with the new Garment Type's color options, it generates the new DIV underneath the previous color options.

It's kind of difficult to explain, but I've included the code below so you can see for yourselves!

Any and all help is appreciated, thank you!

**UPDATE**: I've put the code into a JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/oym3ondo/

First select Tshirt. Then choose gildan 5000. Then choose Gildan 2000 and so on. It will keep creating the color menus instead of replacing the existing one.

```
<!--DYNAMIC FORM SCRIPT -->
<script type="text/javascript">
// Place in this array the ID of the element you want to hide
var hide=['T-Shirts','Hoodies','Tanks','Long-Sleeves','Gildan_5000','Gildan_2000','Gildan_64000','Gildan_5000L','Tultex_Uni_0202TC','Tultex_Ladies_0213TC','AA_Uni_2001','AA_Ladies_2102','Anvil_980','Gildan_Pull_18500','Gildan_Zip_18600','Tultex_Pull_0320TC','Tultex_Zip_0331TC','Gildan_2200_Tank','Tultex_Uni_Tank','Tultex_Ladies_Tank','Anvil_986_Tank','AA_Tank','Gildan_5400_Long_Sleeve','Gildan_18000_Crewneck','Tultex_Raglan'];
function setOpt()
{
resetOpt(); // Call the resetOpt function. Hide some elements in the "hide" array.
for(var i=0,sel=document.getElementsByTagName('select');i<sel.length;i++)
    {
    sel[i].onchange=function()
        {
        if(this.parentNode.tagName.toLowerCase()!='div')
            resetOpt(); // Hides the elements in "hide" array when the first select element is choosen
        try
            {
            document.getElementById(this.value).style.display='';
            }
        catch(e){} ; // When the value of the element is not an element ID
        }
    }
}

window.addEventListener?window.addEventListener('load',setOpt,false):
window.attachEvent('onload',setOpt);

function resetOpt()
{
for(var i=0;i<hide.length;i++) 
    document.getElementById(hide[i]).style.display='none'; // Hide the elements in "hide" array
}
</script>

</head>

<body>

<table width="900px" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <td colspan="4"><center><strong>Shirt/Design Info</strong></center></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="150px" align="right">Select Garment:</td>
    <td width="300px" align="left">
        <select name="garment" size="1">
            <option>Please Select A Garment Type:</option>
            <option value="T-Shirts">T-Shirts</option>
            <option value="Hoodies">Hoodies</option>
            <option value="Tanks">Tanks</option>
            <option value="Long-Sleeves">Long Sleeves</option>        
        </select>
    </td>
    <td width="150px" align="right">Select Garment Style:</td>
    <td width="300px" align="left">
        <div id="T-Shirts">
        <select name="tshirt_type">
        <option>Please Select A T-Shirt Style:</option>
        <option value="Gildan_5000">Gildan 5000</option>
        <option value="Gildan_2000">Gildan Ultra 2000</option>
        <option value="Gildan_64000">Gildan Softstyle 64000</option>
        <option value="Gildan_5000L">Gildan Ladies 5000L</option>
        <option value="Tultex_Uni_0202TC">Tultex Unisex 0202TC</option>
        <option value="Tultex_Ladies_0213TC">Tultex Ladies 0213TC</option>
        <option value="AA_Uni_2001">American Apparel 2001</option>
        <option value="AA_Ladies_2102">American Apparel Ladies 2102</option>
        <option value="Anvil_980">Anvil 980</option>
        </select>
        </div>

        <div id="Hoodies">
        <select name="hoodie_type">
        <option>Please Select A Hoodie Style:</option>
        <option value="Gildan_Pull_18500">Gildan 18500 Pullover Hoodie</option>
        <option value="Gildan_Zip_18600">Gildan 18600 Zip Up Hoodie</option>
        <option value="Tultex_Pull_0320TC">Tultex 0320TC Pullover Hood</option>
        <option value="Tultex_Zip_0331TC">Tultex 0331TC Zipper Hood</option>
        </select>
        </div>

        <div id="Tanks">
        <select name="tank_type">
        <option>Please Select A Tank Top Style:</option>
        <option value="Gildan_2200_Tank">Gildan 2200 Tank</option>
        <option value="Tultex_Uni_Tank">Tultex Unisex Tank</option>
        <option value="Tultex_Ladies_Tank">Tultex Ladies Racerback Tank</option>
        <option value="Anvil_986_Tank">Anvil 986 Tank</option>
        <option value="AA_Tank">American Apparel Tank</option>
        </select>
        </div>

        <div id="Long-Sleeves">
        <select name="long_sleeve_type">
        <option>Please Select A Long Sleeve Style:</option>
        <option value="Gildan_5400_Long_Sleeve">Gildan 5400 Long Sleeve Tee</option>
        <option value="Gildan_18000_Crewneck">Gildan 18000 Crewneck</option>
        <option value="Tultex_Raglan">Tultex Unisex 3/4 Raglan Tee</option>
        </select>
        </div>


    </td>  
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="150px" align="right">Select Shirt Color:</td>    
    <td width="300px" align="left">

        <!--T-SHIRT COLORS-->       

        <div id="Gildan_5000">
        <select name="Garment_Color">
        <option>Please Select A Color</option>
        <option value="Green" style="background-color:#0F0;">Green</option>
        <option>Opt2</option>
        <option>Opt3</option>
        </select>
        </div>

        <div id="Gildan_2000">
        <select name="Garment_Color">
        <option>Please Select A Color</option>
        <option value="Green" style="background-color:#0F0;">Green</option>
        <option>Opt2</option>
        <option>Opt3</option>
        </select>
        </div>

        <div id="Gildan_64000">
        <select name="Garment_Color">
        <option>Please Select A Color</option>
        <option value="Green" style="background-color:#0F0;">Green</option>
        <option>Opt2</option>
        <option>Opt3</option>
        </select>
        </div>    

        <div id="Gildan_5000L">
        <select name="Garment_Color">
        <option>Please Select A Color</option>
        <option value="Green" style="background-color:#0F0;">Green</option>
        <option>Opt2</option>
        <option>Opt3</option>
        </select>
        </div>  

        <div id="Tultex_Uni_0202TC">
        <select name="Garment_Color">
        <option>Please Select A Color</option>
        <option value="Green" style="background-color:#0F0;">Green</option>
        <option>Opt2</option>
        <option>Opt3</option>
        </select>
        </div>   

        <div id="Tultex_Ladies_0213TC">
        <select name="Garment_Color">
        <option>Please Select A Color</option>
        <option value="Green" style="background-color:#0F0;">Green</option>
        <option>Opt2</option>
        <option>Opt3</option>
        </select>
        </div>  

        <div id="AA_Uni_2001">
        <select name="Garment_Color">
        <option>Please Select A Color</option>
        <option value="Green" style="background-color:#0F0;">Green</option>
        <option>Opt2</option>
        <option>Opt3</option>
        </select>
        </div>  

        <div id="AA_Ladies_2102">
        <select name="Garment_Color">
        <option>Please Select A Color</option>
        <option value="Green" style="background-color:#0F0;">Green</option>
        <option>Opt2</option>
        <option>Opt3</option>
        </select>
        </div>     

        <div id="Anvil_980">
        <select name="Garment_Color">
        <option>Please Select A Color</option>
        <option value="Green" style="background-color:#0F0;">Green</option>
        <option>Opt2</option>
        <option>Opt3</option>
        </select>
        </div>       

        <!--HOODIE COLORS-->

        <div id="Gildan_Pull_18500">
        <select name="Garment_Color">
        <option>Please Select A Color</option>
        <option value="Green" style="background-color:#0F0;">Green</option>
        <option>Opt2</option>
        <option>Opt3</option>
        </select>
        </div>    

        <div id="Gildan_Zip_18600">
        <select name="Garment_Color">
        <option>Please Select A Color</option>
        <option value="Green" style="background-color:#0F0;">Green</option>
        <option>Opt2</option>
        <option>Opt3</option>
        </select>
        </div>    

        <div id="Tultex_Pull_0320TC">
        <select name="Garment_Color">
        <option>Please Select A Color</option>
        <option value="Green" style="background-color:#0F0;">Green</option>
        <option>Opt2</option>
        <option>Opt3</option>
        </select>
        </div>     

        <div id="Tultex_Zip_0331TC">
        <select name="Garment_Color">
        <option>Please Select A Color</option>
        <option value="Green" style="background-color:#0F0;">Green</option>
        <option>Opt2</option>
        <option>Opt3</option>
        </select>
        </div>    

        <!--TANK COLORS-->     

        <div id="Gildan_2200_Tank">
        <select name="Garment_Color">
        <option>Please Select A Color</option>
        <option value="Green" style="background-color:#0F0;">Green</option>
        <option>Opt2</option>
        <option>Opt3</option>
        </select>
        </div>      

        <div id="Tultex_Uni_Tank">
        <select name="Garment_Color">
        <option>Please Select A Color</option>
        <option value="Green" style="background-color:#0F0;">Green</option>
        <option>Opt2</option>
        <option>Opt3</option>
        </select>
        </div>     

        <div id="Tultex_Ladies_Tank">
        <select name="Garment_Color">
        <option>Please Select A Color</option>
        <option value="Green" style="background-color:#0F0;">Green</option>
        <option>Opt2</option>
        <option>Opt3</option>
        </select>
        </div>   

        <div id="Anvil_986_Tank">
        <select name="Garment_Color">
        <option>Please Select A Color</option>
        <option value="Green" style="background-color:#0F0;">Green</option>
        <option>Opt2</option>
        <option>Opt3</option>
        </select>
        </div>  

        <div id="AA_Tank">
        <select name="Garment_Color">
        <option>Please Select A Color</option>
        <option value="Green" style="background-color:#0F0;">Green</option>
        <option>Opt2</option>
        <option>Opt3</option>
        </select>
        </div>

        <!--Long Sleeve Colors-->

        <div id="Gildan_5400_Long_Sleeve">
        <select name="Garment_Color">
        <option>Please Select A Color</option>
        <option value="Green" style="background-color:#0F0;">Green</option>
        <option>Opt2</option>
        <option>Opt3</option>
        </select>
        </div>       

        <div id="Gildan_18000_Crewneck">
        <select name="Garment_Color">
        <option>Please Select A Color</option>
        <option value="Green" style="background-color:#0F0;">Green</option>
        <option>Opt2</option>
        <option>Opt3</option>
        </select>
        </div>    

        <div id="Tultex_Raglan">
        <select name="Garment_Color">
        <option>Please Select A Color</option>
        <option value="Green" style="background-color:#0F0;">Green</option>
        <option>Opt2</option>
        <option>Opt3</option>
        </select>
        </div>                                                                                                 

    </td>  
    <td width="150px" align="right">Quantity:</td>    
    <td width="300px" align="left"><input name="quantity" type="text" size="10" maxlength="4" /></td> 
  </tr>


</table>

</body>
```

Comment: The first `<td>` in the table should be `<th>`

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem? I tried copying your code, and I don't see the additional menus when I choose from the main menu.

Comment: I've put the code into JSFiddle! First select Tshirt. Then choose gildan 5000. Then choose Gildan 2000 and so on. It will keep creating the color menus instead of replacing the existing one.

Comment: You only call `resetOpt()` when the parent of the SELECT is not a DIV. The parent of the Garment Style menu is a DIV, so you don't hide the old color menus before showing the new one.

Comment: You even have a comment saying this is what you want: hide the elements in the "hide" array when selecting something from the first menu. They aren't hidden when selecting from the second menu.